# React useState hook does not update the lonlat value in OSM

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I´m stucked with not updating react useState hook setPosition(lonLat) line 34. Could someone advise me please why that does not working? The position const is still a 'test' string.

````
import 'ol/ol.css'
import Map from "ol/Map"
import OSM from "ol/source/OSM"
import Tile from "ol/layer/Tile"
import View from "ol/View"
import {fromLonLat, toLonLat} from 'ol/proj'

export const useMap = () => {
    const [position, setPosition] = useState('test')

    useEffect(() => {
        // initialMap
        const initialMap = new Map({
            target: "map",
            layers: [
                new Tile({
                source: new OSM(),
                }),
            ],
            view: new View({
                center: fromLonLat([15, 50]),
                zoom: 8,
            }),
        })
        
        // pick up coordinates
        initialMap.on('click', (e) => {
            const coordinate = e.coordinate
            const lonLat = toLonLat(coordinate)

            // I cant understand, why the next setPosition(lonlat) does not update the cosnt position
            setPosition(lonLat)
            console.log(position)
        })
        
    }, [position]);
    

    return { position }
};```
````

Answer (score 0):

SetState is async, so

change:

```
setPosition(lonLat)
console.log(position)
```

to:

```
setPosition(lonLat, () => {
  console.log(position)
})
```

Comment: I have tryed such solution and have got this error: react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().